# How to resampling o multidimensional event without losing information

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset representing a time series
The time series has 165 events

Each unique event has 15 rows, FX1, FX2, … FX15

The time between each row is 1 minute so one event takes 15 minutes

Each row has 6 features F1,F2,F3,T1,T2,T3
All values are numeric and integers values

Here is an example of an event :

This event started at 2000/01/01 00:00:00 and ended at 2000/01/01 00:15:00

The first row in the event has F1=3,F2=-4,…T3=45

```
                   time  F1   F2   F3  T1  T2   T3
0   2000/01/01 00:01:00  94  -76    0  47   9  -20
1   2000/01/01 00:02:00  -2   85   14  79  92  -95
2   2000/01/01 00:03:00  -3   13 -100  33  74  -43
3   2000/01/01 00:04:00  39   64  -29  32 -73  -44
4   2000/01/01 00:05:00  80   44    3  73  56 -100
5   2000/01/01 00:06:00 -19  -51  -77  32  72   24
6   2000/01/01 00:07:00  79  -69  -87   4  20   19
7   2000/01/01 00:08:00  68    6   95 -76  34   58
8   2000/01/01 00:09:00  26  -59   24  79 -43   48
9   2000/01/01 00:10:00  71    8  -85 -15 -45  -56
10  2000/01/01 00:11:00  51   98    6 -53 -39    5
11  2000/01/01 00:12:00  99   73  -48  -1  64   56
12  2000/01/01 00:13:00 -12   13  -63  51  36   95
13  2000/01/01 00:14:00   8 -100   54  91 -56  -32
```

My question is this

Can I convert one event to just one row without losing information?

Let's say I use Panda data frame resample() method for downsampling

Think of it like resampling a dataset in this case resampling to 15 minutes will create a unique row I think but will the resulting unidimensional data lack any information?

So the desired output for the above data frame will be something like this

```
                 time  F1   F2   F3   T1   T2     T3
 2000/01/01 00:01:00  XF1  XF2  XF3  xT1  xT2    xT3
```

Where XF1 is the value that best represents the array of 14 values that F1 took from 0 to 14 ( 94, -2, -3, 39, 80, -19, 79, ....8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"time": [f"2000/01/01 00:{i:02}:00" for i in range(1, 60)]}
    | {
        key: [random.randrange(-100, 100) for _ in range(1, 60)]
        for key in ("F1", "F2", "F3", "T1", "T2", "T3")
    }
)

print(df.head(30))

# Output
                   time  F1  F2  F3  T1  T2   T3
0   2000/01/01 00:01:00  44 -91   5 -23  97   14
1   2000/01/01 00:02:00 -38  46 -14  -5 -66   39
2   2000/01/01 00:03:00  70 -63 -28 -53  53   77
3   2000/01/01 00:04:00  33 -16  82  98  54   95
4   2000/01/01 00:05:00 -51 -89 -52 -88 -68  -61
5   2000/01/01 00:06:00 -64  69  25 -98  21   63
6   2000/01/01 00:07:00 -52  51 -34  35 -47   83
7   2000/01/01 00:08:00 -10  10 -87 -49  75    7
8   2000/01/01 00:09:00 -51 -95  25 -49 -43  -13
9   2000/01/01 00:10:00 -16  88 -23  -3 -17   71
10  2000/01/01 00:11:00   4 -97   3  53 -35  -83
11  2000/01/01 00:12:00 -94 -17 -88  -5  41   60
12  2000/01/01 00:13:00  91 -14  43  79  -8   14
13  2000/01/01 00:14:00  94  -1 -57   7 -21   91
14  2000/01/01 00:15:00 -60  -2  39 -56 -61   24
15  2000/01/01 00:16:00 -20 -83  30  68 -97  -87
16  2000/01/01 00:17:00   7  70 -65  49  13  -66
17  2000/01/01 00:18:00  29 -70  78  84 -80   -5
18  2000/01/01 00:19:00  57 -57 -78 -75  29  -12
19  2000/01/01 00:20:00  -1 -48 -91  89  25   88
20  2000/01/01 00:21:00 -60 -90   6  34 -77   34
21  2000/01/01 00:22:00 -28   7 -33 -64  42   56
22  2000/01/01 00:23:00 -29  85  45  29 -20  -38
23  2000/01/01 00:24:00  40 -26  17  18  50 -100
24  2000/01/01 00:25:00 -74  60 -50  -3  81  -91
25  2000/01/01 00:26:00  35  47 -90  19  48  -47
26  2000/01/01 00:27:00 -32  34 -43  33  26   26
27  2000/01/01 00:28:00  74  12 -11 -97 -20  -29
28  2000/01/01 00:29:00  58 -90  -7 -88  29  -89
29  2000/01/01 00:30:00  39 -51 -88 -94 -26  -27
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
new_df = (
    df.set_index("time").resample("15T").agg(lambda x: int(np.mean(x)))
)  # 15 min. resampling
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

                     F1  F2  F3  T1  T2  T3
time
2000-01-01 00:00:00  -2 -15 -14  -7   2  32
2000-01-01 00:15:00   0 -10 -16   2   0 -22
2000-01-01 00:30:00   7  -3 -13 -12   0  24
2000-01-01 00:45:00  -1   0  -5 -23 -12 -23
```

Without more context, it's impossible to determine what would be the best representation of the resampled values, so I chose the mean value, but you can replace the lambda function with anything more suitable.

Also, I don't think you will be able to avoid losing *some* information, as resampling/aggregating necessarily comes at a cost.

Comment: Could you please explain your response ? I see the dataset get bigger instead of smaller

Comment: I clarified the question

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. Cheers.